# use different redirector depending on the proxy squid port used?

Tags: redirect, proxy, port, jpeg, squid

I want to use different redirector, according to the port the users connect to, on the same squid process.

is it possible to do it in config file?

or something else then changing source

ex: I want to compress jpg quality 50% on port 3128, and 10% on port 3129, and so on.

or, how can I tell squid compression ratio the user want? (compression is done by redirecting to a new compressed file)

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

First, you can't have more than one redirector. Second, if you want to resize images, you need an ICAP server.

Squid 3.x supports ICAP servers. Squid sends the entire requests and the replies to the ICAP server to modify the content. Also it's possible to configure Squid to send the username that requested the page in a headers, so you can what you want without any problem.